# htaccess www sub domain redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

My problem

I have a sub domain pointing to a different server. The server has a SSL, thus when a user types in the sub domain: `https://my.maindomain.co` it works great. Using htaccess I'm trying to redirect all users who type in the following web address: `https://www.my.maindomain.co` or the `http://` equivalent to the correct version (https://my.maindomain.co).

I thought the below would work nicely but it does not:

```
# rule for removing www on sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.maindomain\.co)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Anybody help me out with this?

For reference I am placing this code in the htaccess on the maindomain.co server, which is hosted on a different server to my.maindomain.co

Comment: @anubhava No other redirect rules are applied

Comment: See updated question, I've just thought of that. Should it be on the sub domain server and NOT the server of the main domain?

Comment: Yes it should be in the htaccess of sub domain server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule for your subdomain on the server where the sub domain is hosted. It should take care of your requirements.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my\.example\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://my.example.co%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note you must have a **valid ssl certificate** for `www.my.example.co` for this to work if they enter `www.my.example.co`. Otherwise it will still handle redirecting `http://my.example.co` to `https://my.example.co`.

Comment: What you say re: where I should put your code, do you think my above code should be placed on the htaccess of the sub domain server NOT the server of the main domain?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It has to be on the server that's serving the subdomain. Not the main domain server because it's not pointing there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what do you mean by 'it does not work'? It would be helpful, if you could specify what is the exact error you get when you try to load https://www.my.subdomain.co

Apart from that i can think of one more factor, if you are using **apache** server, u might want to add '**www.my.tutella.co**' to **ServerAlias** under virtual host configuration of **my.tutella.co**

Answer (score 0):

[You don't actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)

In the `.htaccess` of your subdomain (or, if you have access to the main Apache configuration, that's more efficient than `.htaccess` files) you can use this directive:

```
Redirect / https://my.example.co/
```

...this uses `mod_alias` and is much easier to understand and troubleshoot than the `mod_rewrite` equivalents.

Comment: That's actually not correct. Redirect is [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect). And for his complete requirement it is better to use mod_rewrite which is not that difficult to understand. He has several requirements including checking for https or not in addition to carrying over the URI. He's correct with what he's using.